# How to split string in batch file using words inside the string

Tags: string, batch-file, variables, split, var

For example, I have this string in another variable:

```
444455556666&X=697&Y=250
```

I want to get the *number* after **"&X="** in a variable and the *number* after **"&Y="** in another variable. Is it possible in batch file?
Notice: the number **444455556666** is VARIABLE (it can be it can be shorter or longer, so i can't split with the position)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a fine format there: If you split it by `&`, you get a number, `X=nnn`, and `Y=nnn`. Skip the first and use the second and third:

```
set "var=444455556666&X=697&Y=250"
for /f "tokens=2,3 delims=&" %%x in ("%var%") do set "%%x"&set "%%y"
echo %x%,%y%
```

Comment: and... what if i had this: "444455556666, 777788889" (any two changing number, divided only by a comma and a space) and i want to get the first number in a variable and the second number in another variable?

Comment: `for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=, " %%a in ("444455556666, 777788889") do set "first=%%a"&set "second=%%b"` Note: if you use a space as delimiter, it has to be the *last* delim-char.